# Custom ListView adapter throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, custom-adapter

I have some problems with my custom adapter for a `ListView`. I'm unsure if my problems lies with the xml files, with the data or with the instantiation of the `ListView`. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when I set the adapter. The adapter class:

```
public class InboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private List<MailInbox> mails;

    public InboxAdapter(Context context, List<MailInbox> mails)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.mails = mails;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mails.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int item) {
        return mails.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        MailInbox entry = mails.get(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mail_list_row, null);
        }

        ImageView mailImg = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mail_thumb);
        boolean read = entry.IsRead;

        if(read)
        {
            //Set "read" image
            mailImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.message);
        } else
        {
            //Set "unread" image
            mailImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.message);
        }

        TextView author = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mail_text);
        TextView body = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mail_detail);
        TextView date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mail_date);

        author.setText(entry.AuthorName);
        body.setText(entry.MessageBody);
        date.setText(entry.CreatedAt);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The `Activity` where I use it:

```
public class InboxActivity extends SherlockActivity 
{
    private ListView list;
    private GetMessagesConnection mMessages;

    public String kidID;

    public InboxActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.inbox_layout);        

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            kidID = extras.getString("kidID");
        }

        new GetMails().execute();
    }

    private void setUpList()
    {
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mail_list);      

        ArrayList<MailInbox> mails = new ArrayList<MailInbox>();

        for(int i = 0; i < mMessages.myMail.size(); i++)
        {
            MailInbox inbox = new MailInbox();

            inbox.AuthorName = mMessages.myMail.get(i).AuthorName;
            inbox.CreatedAt = mMessages.myMail.get(i).CreatedAt;
            inbox.MessageBody = mMessages.myMail.get(i).MessageBody;
            inbox.IsRead = mMessages.myMail.get(i).IsRead;

            System.out.println("Author: " + inbox.AuthorName);
            System.out.println("Time: " + inbox.CreatedAt);
            System.out.println("Message: " + inbox.MessageBody);
            System.out.println("Read: " + inbox.IsRead);

            mails.add(inbox);
        }

        int length = mails.size();
        System.out.println("Size: " + length);

        InboxAdapter adapter = new InboxAdapter(this, mails);

        // It crashes here with a Nullpointer Exception
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class GetMails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener
    {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(InboxActivity.this, "", "Henter beskeder...", true);
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused)
        {
                mMessages = new GetMessagesConnection();

                mMessages.kidID = kidID;

                mMessages.connection();

                return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
        {           
            dialog.dismiss();
            setUpList();
        }

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            cancel(true);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

*mail_list*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mail_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" >    
</ListView>
```

*mail_list_row*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:background="@drawable/listselector"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mail_thumb"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgdesc"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mail_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mail_thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mail_detail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mail_thumb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mail_text"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"     
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mail_date"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mail_detail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mail_text"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know what could be `null`. I've been trying to solve this for several hours.
Error log:

```
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at com.cim.daycare.InboxActivity.setUpList(InboxActivity.java:75)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at com.cim.daycare.InboxActivity.access$2(InboxActivity.java:36)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at com.cim.daycare.InboxActivity$GetMails.onPostExecute(InboxActivity.java:101)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at com.cim.daycare.InboxActivity$GetMails.onPostExecute(InboxActivity.java:1)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-14 19:55:45.525: E/AndroidRuntime(2509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the error output from the Log ?

Comment: where you have declare ->mails

Comment: please provide the error log .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the activity `InboxActivity` you set the content view to `R.layout.inbox_layout`(I don't see this file in your question) and you search for the `ListView` with the id `R.id.mail_list`. A `ListView` with this `id` exist in the `mail_list.xml` file. Are you sure that the content view for the `InboxActivity` isn't `R.layout.mail_list`:

```
//...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mail_list);        
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
//...
```

Also:

- Please don't declare a constructor for the `InboxActivity`, initialize what you want in the `onCreate` method(this is how things work in the android world).
- Do you handle the cases when `extras` is `null`? (If the `extras` is `null` then `kidID` will also be `null` and this could put you in trouble in the `GetMessagesConnection` class if you don't handle this scenario).

Comment: What an incredibly stupid mistake :) I had begun designing the xml layout two different times... And thanks for your other notes! I'm primarily an iOS developer and I'm learning Android, so all notes like that are extremely valuable to me...

Comment: @user1368800 Don't worry it was a honest mistake. When you get a `NullPointerException` on a `View` that you searched with `findViewById` you should always look if it isn't something wrong with the layout files.

Answer (score 1):

You get the instance to your list like this `list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mail_list);` which means you are checking your current layout for that ID, but your current layout is set to `setContentView(R.layout.inbox_layout);`

What is inbox_layout? You haven't showed us the XML?Did you mean to set it to `setContentView(R.layout.mail_list);` instead?

Edit: Also, you may want to look into using a ViewHolder in your custom adapter to avoid making repetitive calls to `findViewByID(...)`. Take a look at this tutorial: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/